# Windows Binary for Glade 3.18.3?

Tags: c, gtk, glade

Is there any build of Glade 3.18.3 as a Windows Binary? Would really like to make use of GTK3+ with Glade however they seem to have stopped at 3.8.5 :(  which only supports GTK 2.24.

Comment: GTK+ 3 is no longer distributed as standalone packages on Windows; you will need to use MSYS2 to get it. Once you have MSYS2, you can use `pacman` to install both GTK+ 3 and glade. See the GTK+ website for details.

Comment: @andlabs Can you explain what MSYS2 is? I'm just trying to following instructions on getting VisualRuby which says "Install Glade for gtk3 from the Glade Homepage. (look for windows installer)" But the latest Windows Installer for Glade is for gtk2.

Comment: It is quite unfortunate that gtk3 is no longer distributed as a standalone package on windows. With the rise of WSL1 and WSL2, for me it is now easier to just write on linux and let windows users use WSL1/WSL2 too, since that is actually less of a hassle than the other "recommended" install options. It's really weird to me that the gtk-dev does not distributed standalone packages anymore; the claimed "it is distributed with the app itself" simply is NOT true for all apps as such, even less so if you are a small hobbyist developer. Dunno what the gtk dev team is thinking here...

Answer (score 5):

You can still install the latest version of `Glade` by using the `MSYS2 pacman` package manager:

> #### Installing Glade
>
> Next we're going to install glade, make sure you have a MSYS console open
>
> To search for the glade packages:
>   
>   `pacman -Ss glade`
>   
>   To install for 64Bit Windows:
>   
>   `pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glade`
>
> We can now run glade via the exe `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\glade.exe`

1. http://msys2.org
2. http://grbd.github.io/posts/2016/01/29/gtksharp-part-2-setting-up-glade/

Comment: Problem is that this is tedious (and if you don't think it is, well - I guess you don't fully understand the problem domain of getting this to work for elderly people, to give one example). WSL1 and WSL2 actually are simpler to use and setup compared to msys these days. This is something not everyone seems to understand yet. (WSL1 and WSL2 are not a perfect solution either, in particular for older systems.)